# Why does QtGui.QSound just not play anything at all?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4

So, I am trying to play a sound in my application. Typically the sound needs to be played after a the end of a countdown and then user-interaction is stopped.

But, the problem is `QSound` just ends up playing nothing at all. I have tried mp3, wav etc. without any result.

What could be the possible reason?

I've tried this both on Linux and Windows. Here's what I tried (both play and play2 functions):

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 200)
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Play", self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.play)
        self.btn.move(50, 80)

    def play(self):
        c = QtGui.QSound("1.mp3")
        c.play()

    def play2(self):
        QtGui.QSound.play("1.mp3")
```

Neither of them work!

**EDIT**: I used Phonon for my purpose, but I have no idea why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call [QSound.isAvailable()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsound.html#isAvailable) to check whether the necessary sound facilities are available on your platform (but note that this may produce a false positive on Windows).

When I try this on Linux, is prints `False`, even though phonon is installed and I can play audio using the PyQt Phonon module.

This may be because I don't have NAS support built in (I haven't checked), which is the key requirement that determines availability on X11. For other platforms, see the [Detailed Description](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsound.html#details) for QSound - in particular, note that QSound will only play WAV files on Windows.